# ASP.NET MVC - Return JavascriptResult and Json parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

Here is the scenario

In MVC, it is easy to return a Javascript to be executed on the client

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{       
    return JavaScript("alert('Hello world!');");            
}
```

On the client, I have a Javascript that takes a JSon object as parameter

Something similar to this :

```
function open(options) {...}
```

I wanted to call this function from my action passing it a json object generated on the server
so I wrote this

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
      var viewData = new {...};
      return JavaScript( "open('" + Json(viewData) + "')" );          
}
```

However, when my Javascript function get called, I don't get any data but this: `open('System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult')`

I will appreciate any help on this matter

Thanks

Comment: can you show me please all your javascript code?? please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Json method returns a JsonResult. Not a JSON string. You could use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
      JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      var viewData = new {...};
      return JavaScript( "open('" + serializer.Serialize(viewData) + "')" );          
}
```

Depending on how your client side `open` method works you may need to send the json data as a json object instead of a string by simply removing the ' around the method argument.

Comment: I removed the ' around the method argument and this effectively worked.

Thank you so much for your help